# Add shareable custom data to event MS graph api

Tags: events, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Iam trying to create an event within the ms calendar, and add application specific information to this event, this specific information should be added by user 1 and when user 2 accepts the event they should also be able to see the custom data. I'm doing this by calling the events' endpoint on the MS graph API.

I've been adding the data object as an openExtension to the user when creating a new event. Furthermore, I figured out that an openExtension is only populated for the user who added it (so the user, who created the event, can also retrieve the extension data). The user who accepted the event won't see the extension data.

I'm trying to figure out an alternative now, to be able to share custom data from user 1 to user 2.
I would want to create an event with user 1, add the custom data to the event, pull the event with user 2 including the custom data.

So far I didn't find a solution within the MS graph api docs, I'm basically looking for the ability to add custom data to an event which all users who accept the event can also see and filter for within the get query to the ms graph api, any help is appreciated!